# Volant, Steuer, Lenkrad

Tags: usage, regional, vocabulary

Diese drei Wörter sind alle Synonyme, aber welches wird am meisten benutzt? Ich glaube, dass Volant auf Deutsch ziemlich ungewohnt ist, aber ich habe keine Ahnung von den anderen zwei.

Gibt es velleicht auch regionale Unterschiede (zum Beispiel zwischen Deutschland und Österreich)?

Comment: Auf Französisch gibt es die Redensart "Au volant la vue, c'est la vie!" (Die Sicht/Aussicht am Steuer/Lenkrad, das ist das Leben!).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich habe das Wort *Volant* noch nie in diesem Kontext gehört. Laut [Farlex](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/volant) ist

> **Volant** ein Stoffbesatz auf Rocksäumen, der gekräuselt ist

das **Steuer**  (nicht mit *die Steuer* zu verwechseln) bezeichnet eine Vorrichtung, mit der man ein Auto, ein Schiff, ein Flugzeug oder einen Zug *steuert*.

Das **Lenkrad** ist nur in Autos anzutreffen und bezeichnet das runde Teil im Cockpit, mitsamt Hupe, Airbags und *Lenkradsteuerung* fürs Radio.

Der Ausdruck **am Steuer** ist gleichbedeutend mit **hinter dem Lenkrad**. Es wird gerne verwendet im Sinne vom *Auto fahren*: *am Steuer sitzen*, *sich ans Steuer setzen*, *Trunkenheit am Steuer*. Irgendwie würde es merkwürdig klingen, wenn man statt *Steuer* das Wort *Lenkrad* benutzen würde. Warum? Kann niemand sagen - so ist die Sprache halt. Es liegt vielleicht daran, dass wir nicht spezifizieren wollen, welche Art des Steuers es ist - ob es sich nun um ein Lenkrad, ein Joystik, oder Gedankensteuerung handelt. Hauptsache, man steuert das Auto.

Das **Lenkrad** ist also eine Art von einem **Steuer** - genauso wie bspw. die **Lenkstange** beim Fahrrad. **Lenkrad** und **Lenkstange** sind Namen von irgendwelchen Teilen, wobei das **Steuer** ein allgemeiner Begriff ist.

Comment: doch, Volant ist (österreichisch) veraltet für Lenkrad: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Volant (2)

Comment: Danke für die Ergänzung!

Comment: Das Steuer ist mE mehr als das Lenkrad, es beinhaltet auch Pedale, Kupplung, Schalthebel und andere Bedienelemente. Volant ist ein Synonym für Lenkrad und wird jdf in Ö auch noch durchaus verwendet. Duden nennt es _veraltend_, dem kann man sich wohl anschließen.

Comment: @Ingmar völlig richtig. Ich wollte aber nicht genaue Definitionen angegeben, sondern den OP in die richtige Denkschiene lenken, was es mit dem Unterschied auf sich hat. Da ich selber Deutsch als Fremdsprache gelernt habe, weiß ich wie schwierig es ist, manche Wörter zu unterscheiden. Da sind solche einfachen Denkanstöße Gold wert. Fühl dich frei, meinen Beitrag zu bearbeiten.

Comment: Ich glaubte, dass Volant wahrscheinlich ein Österreichisches Wort würde, weil es genauso auf Tschechisch heißt und es gibt mehrere Tschechische Wörter auf Österreichisch als auf deutsches Deutsch. Wenn es veraltet ist, soll ich es aber nicht auf Deutsch (besonders in Deutschland) nutzen, weil die Leute würden denken, dass es komisch ist, oder?

Comment: "Lenkstange" beim Fahrrad ist zwar technisch korrekt, aber umgangssprachlich habe ich für dieses Bauteil noch nie etwas anderes gehört als "Lenker". Weshalb ich immer schmunzeln muß, wenn ich in Schweizer Zeitungen Sätze lese wie "Der fehlbare Lenker wurde verzeigt." (Dort meint man mit "Lenker" den Fahrer.)

Comment: @splattne Ich erinnere mich dunkel, "Volant" auch schon in nicht-österreichischen Autozeitschriften gelesen zu haben. Allerdings war das noch im vorigen Jahrtausend.

Comment: @Ingmar: "Das Steuer ist mE mehr als das Lenkrad" - sehe ich nicht so. Unter "das Steuer" verstehe ich nur das Lenkrad (der [Duden auch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Steuer_Lenkung_Ruder)); ggf. ließe es sich sogar als Kurzform von "das Steuerrad" sehen. Nicht zu verwechseln mit "die Steuerung", die tatsächlich auf generische Weise auch die komplette Steuerung eines Autos (also alle Steuerungsmöglichkeiten inklusive Pedale, Kupplung etc.) bezeichnen kann.

Comment: @Trademark: Im Fall des Wortes "Volant" wäre ich in Deutschland tatsächlich vorsichtig, da es vermutlich überhaupt nicht verstanden würde.